# in perl ,how to use variable value as hash element

Tags: perl, variables, hash

I am new to Perl, and can't find the answer to the question in the Learning Perl book.

For example I have a array like:

```
my @loop=("op1_sel","op2_sel");
```

and two hash table as:

```
my %op1_sel=(
       "bibuf","000",
       "self","101"
            );
my %op2_sel=(
        "zero","1",
        "temp","0"
            );
```

Now I want to use variables in the loop to loop for the hash table for a particular key
for example:

```
foreach(@loop)
{
     print  ${$_}{"bibuf"} ;
}
```

But it seems not working, I know the `${$_}` part is wrong, can anyone can tell me how 
to fix this ?

Comment: Don't do that. Either put references to the hashes into an array and loop over that, or (if the names are important) put them in a hash and use the values in the array as key names (or just loop over the outer hash if the order isn't important).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't refer to lexical (`my`) variables using the ${$foo} syntax. You could probably make it work if they were package variables, but this would not be the right way to go about it.

The right way to do it is using a nested data structure.

I can see two obvious ways of doing it. You could either make an array of op_sel containing the inner hashes directly, or create a hash of hashes, and then index into that.

So "array of hashes":

```
my @op_sels = (
    {
        bibuf => '000',
        self  => '101',
    },
    {
        zero => '1',
        temp => '0',
    },
);

for my $op (@op_sels) {
    print $$op{bibuf};
}
```

and "hash of hashes":

```
my %op_sels = (
    1 => {
       bibuf => '000',
       self  => '101',
    },
    2 => {
        zero => '1',
        temp => '0',
    },
);

for my $op_key (sort keys %op_sels) {
    print $op_sels{$op_key}{bibuf};
}
```

Comment: thanks very much for you answer with so much detail,the "array of hash" really helped me .i put the reference of hashes in an array ,again thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 5):

Use nested hashes. Like this:

```
my %op;
# put a hash reference into hash, twice
$op{op1_sel} = \%op1_sel; 
$op{op2_sel} = \%op2_sel;

# later ...
foreach (keys %op) {
    print "bibuf of $_: $op{$_}->{bibuf}\n";
};
```

Or, long story short, just

```
my %op = (
    op1_sel => { 
        foo => 1,
        bar => 2,
        # ...
    },
    op2_sel => {
        # ...
    },
};
```

The `{}` construct creates a reference to anonymous hash and is the standard way of handling nested data structures.

See also [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval for this.

```
foreach(@loop)
{
      eval "\%var = \%$_";
      print $var{"bibuf"} ;
}
```

Comment: this worked ,but why ? can you explain it to me ,thanks very much

Comment: The string in the quotes expands like `%var = %op1_sel` or `%var = %op2_sel` in the iterations of the cycle. `eval` executes it as perl script so `%var` is populated with the hash. Then you can use the new variable.

Comment: This might answer the question correctly but I recommend not actually using code like this. Using `eval` and especially referencing variables by their name in another variable is to be generally discouraged (despite very special cases where it might be appropriate). Aspirinnnnn: I hope you've learned a bit but when you have an actual problem similar to this please stick to [Perl references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).